# Split a big loop through several smaller loops by using Task.Run()

Tags: c#, threadpool, multitasking

I have a big loop.

I would like split the process through several smaller loops.

So, I use the following code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> input = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            input.Add(i.ToString());
        }

        int take = 2;
        List<Task<string>> tasks = new List<Task<string>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            // Launch of the tasks
            tasks.Add(Task.Run<string>(() => Process(input.Skip(i * take).Take(take).ToList())));
        }

        Task<string[]> resultTask = Task.WhenAll<string>(tasks.ToArray());

        resultTask.Wait();

        if (resultTask.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
        {
            foreach (var currentText in resultTask.Result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(currentText);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static int number = 0;

    private static string Process(List<string> inputList)
    {
        foreach (var item in inputList)
        {
            // The process here for each small loops.
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        return "Thread " + number++;
    }
}
```

So, I take a part of x items from the big loop et I perform the process on each obtained list.

The problem is that the parameter of the method Process is changed inside the method when the code

```
input.Skip(i * take).Take(take).ToList()
```

is executed.

I tried by cloning the list but I get the same result.

Why ?

EDIT:
The lists would appear like this:

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19

20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29

30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39

...

90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99

Comment: how big of a list are we talking? Lists and threading are a headache.

Comment: I want to build a SqlGeography(LineString) object from a lot of points (SqlGeography). About 100000 iterations/points, maybe more.

Comment: perhaps instead of splitting the list, perhaps the list should be of objects that wrap your base type <string> then handle each iteration in a worker queue or thread. Also using the string data type may slow you down depending on what your data actually looks like, consider creating a struct or class object with the data already formatted for your needs then put that object in a list.

Comment: I have an object with a property. This property has the type SqlGeography which is my base type. In my above example, I use the type string to make it easier.

Comment: ok then yea, I would recommend creating or using an Async safe wrapper for your list, then iterate the list once but execute the tasks in a worker queue

Comment: I have to pass to the method "Process" a list of points and not an item (a point) from my big list because the treatment consists to transform a list of points to a line. This is why I pass a list to the method Process but the problem is that this list is modified in the method process as soon as I create the next list in the method Main. I have the same behavior as if I pass a reference instead of a value to the method Process, even if I clone the list by using a other class inheriting of the interface ICloneable. Why ? So, I don't have a problem if I run step by step in debug.

Comment: Probably a race exception, you have 2 options, 1) wrap the list in an object and lock the object while your method does it work, or 2, forget the ICloneable and just use .ToList() to create a non referenced duplicate.

Comment: I'm going to try the solution 1 because I've already tried the solution 2 with ".ToList()" and even "New List<>(listToProcess)".